# Probability where there is dependent event

Tags: probability

question:

> A lot contains $10$ items out of which $3$ items are defective. If three items are chosen at random without replacement find probability that only first one is defective?

**My approach**: Since selection of items is concerned with order I cannot use combination formula. I can get the answer by doing $(3/10)(7/9)(6/8) = 7/40$. But the events are dependent which means i shouldn't be allowed to use multiplication theorem. Please help.

Comment: "*which means I shouldn't be allowed to use mutliplication theorem*"  Incorrect.  You absolutely can use multiplication... The correct multiplication principle is that $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B\mid A)$.  What you are remembering is that for dependent events you may not use $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$.  You are correctly not doing that here and correctly used the value of $\Pr(B\mid A)$ instead of $\Pr(B)$ (*and similar for the third event*).  Your calculation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $7/9$ or $6/8$ is not the probablity that a ball is not defective in the original ten items, which indicates that you have not used the multiplication theorem. You have used the conditional probablity relation$$P(\text{B1 defective and B2 ok and B3 ok})=P(\text{B3 ok | B1 defective and B2 ok})P(\text{B2 ok | B1 defective})P(\text{B1 defective})$$